# Como usar fadein() para alterar a cor do background?

Tags: jquery, transição

Gostaria de que a tansição entre as cores tivesse um efeito de fade. Quem sabe usando `.fadein()`.

```
$(function () {
    var colors = ["#0099cc", "#c0c0c0", "#587b2e", "#990000", "#000000", "#1C8200", "#987baa", "#981890", "#AA8971", "#1987FC", "#99081E"];
    setInterval(function(){
        var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
        $("body").css("background", selectedcolor);
    }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: Se você usar `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` no seu body todo o conteúdo da sua página vai sumir junto. Caso o objetivo seja mudar apenas a cor de fundo estas duas funções não são as mais recomendadas.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro usar CSS para fazer isso, é bem simples, só precisa de :

```
body{
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

E para mudar a velocidade só precisa de mudar `1s` que quer dizer 1 segundo.

```js
$(function () {
    var colors = ["#0099cc", "#c0c0c0", "#587b2e", "#990000", "#000000", "#1C8200", "#987baa", "#981890", "#AA8971", "#1987FC", "#99081E"];
    setInterval(function () {
        var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
        $("body").css("background", selectedcolor);
    }, 3000);
})
```

```css
body{
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta usar o `animate`, eu sei que em div funciona mas não sei no body.

```
$("body").animate({
          backgroundColor: selectedcolor
}, 1000);
```

Não consegui testar porque estou pelo celular, mas acho que vai rolar.

Comment: Fazer com que a cor mude eu consigo, conforme código acima, o problema é incluir um efeito de fade entre as mudanças.